# Access localhost from Android emulator

Tags: android, localhost, emulation

I am using NancyFx to host a mock server on the following url.

```
127.0.0.1:9000
```

I started Charles to act as a proxy server between the emulator and the mock server.

I add the following proxy settings on the emulator;

```
 server = my ip address
 port = 8888 (port that Charles uses)
```

On my laptops browser, when I go on `127.0.0.1:9000/test` I get the expected output on the window which is "Hello world".

When I go on the SAME url on the emulator I get "This site can't be reached"

I have also tried the following;

```
myIPaddress:9000/test
10.0.2.2:9000/test
```

And I got the same result.

Comment: Both Devices should be in same network.

Comment: `using NancyFx to host a mock server on the following url.

    127.0.0.1:9000`. Why do you bind your server to 127.0.0.1? In this way it will not accept incoming connections from other ip´s.

Comment: I'm not aware of this. What would you recommend I bind my server to?